# Application using Google Maps API

Tags: c#, google-maps

I need to create an application where user can enter Longitude and Latitude in TextBox and it will show a MAP using Google Maps API. I need to show the Acquisition Date of Bird's Eye View and satellite View in the Map. Also an option that user can show the acquisition date to some third person.

How can I retrieve Acquisition Date and get location in Map using Google Maps API? Can you write few lines of C# code to demonstrate?

Comment: So you came here for "demonstrative code" more that to actually learn something?

Comment: C# will not help you much with the Google Maps API, which is all javascript. Additionally, the dates the satellite images were acquired is not available through the API and images change as they become available to Google. You might want to start from the other end, by first finding a service that delivers the data you need, (images with acquisition dates), rather than choosing the service first and then deciding what you want that service to do for you. :-) -- Marcelo.

Comment: Not true.. There are some things that can be done from code-behind usnig a WebClient. For example, our store locator did some sever-side code to call Google APIs to geocode our store addresses.

Comment: @David Stratton - Google Maps API comes in two flavours, javascript or Flash. If you claim there's another Google Maps API please offer a link to its Google documentation. - Your server side code has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Marcelo - I found a link http://tinyurl.com/36qqr8a. In this article, the guy is using .NET ExifLibrary which can extract metadata of provided image. He first gets image from google maps as he claims and then extract the metadata. I can extract according to him but what is the way to get the image against co-ordinates?

Comment: @Umair Ashraf - He's saying that he created an application to "display the map location of a photograph that has GPS embedded metadata". That is, *his own photographs* had GPS embedded data. Very different from obtaining the date when the satellite images were taken.
I looked at one random image from Google Maps and I couldn't see any metadata in it, and in any case, those are not raw original images. From the picture taken by the satellite to the tile image displayed in Google maps there's a lot of processing, such as correcting the slant, adjusting for the projection, etc.

Comment: ah that's weird... I hadn't read the whole and was impressed to read a statement where he said the meta data can be retrieved. Well sorry for that. So is there any way to get the thing I require?

Comment: @Umair Ashraf - Centering the map at a lat/lon entered by the user is no problem, but the date of the satellite images is not available through the API. Also, satellite images are a mosaic of many different photos, which means that within a single map tile of 256x256 pixels you could have parts from several different photos that were taken years apart from each other.
If you have one specific area of interest for your application you can look at the copyright notice at the bottom of the map and try to contact the supplier of the images and ask them about the date, but it's a long shot. :-)

Comment: I don't need the images at all. But what I need is date of capture of particular image against each provided co-ordinates. I think this is not possible without image being available. Or is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2nd link to come up on a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=google+maps+api+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) has all the info you need:

http://jmayo.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5F243997972597CE!208.entry

Comment: That article is from 2005. At least two major versions of the Google Maps API have been deprecated since then. (V1 and V2). The current version is V3 and it uses a rather different structure to the previous versions, so I wouldn't expect those wrappers to work very well.

Comment: The link presented is old, and following it gets you to the top of a blog that goes on and on and on ... When I eventually scrolled back to 2005 I found the entry consisted mostly of three links to CodeProject articles. I'll copy the links here for those who are interested, despite Marcelo's warning: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11521/Lat-Lays-Flat-Part-1-A-Google-Maps-NET-Control http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11600/Lat-Lays-Flat-Part-2-Advanced-Google-Maps-NET-Cont http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11864/Lat-Lays-Flat-Part-3-Creating-A-Google-Maps-NET-Co

Comment: And here's an updated link to the blog entry in question: http://linqtotwitter.wordpress.com/2005/10/05/google-maps-api-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

@Marcelo, You're talking like you wrote Google Maps API yourself!

Google maps has Web Service API:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html

YES, you can use Google API using WebClient:
http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/UsingGoogleMapsforGeocodinginC.aspx

That will bring you the lat and long for the address

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source C# wrapper http://gglgeo.codeplex.com/ . The project is under MIT license.